# Cannot optimize network URL, skipping

Tags: requirejs, r.js

I try to optimize my `require.js` scripts ...

```
r.js -o app.build.js
```

... but got warning:

```
Tracing dependencies for: main
Cannot optimize network URL, skipping: http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0-stable/?load=package.standard&lang=ru-RU
```

... and as expected in optimized script part of code which use skipped script don't work.

How to work around this? Is the only solution to download this network script to disk manually?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [`empty:` scheme](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty). Basically, in the configuration you pass to `r.js`, your `paths` setting should set the path of network resources to `"empty:"`.

Here's a generic example (from the doc I link to above) with jQuery:

```
({
  baseUrl: ".",
  name: "main",
  out: "main-built.js",
  paths: {
    jquery: "empty:"
  }
})
```